# Qmake configuration using Buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, qmake, buildroot

I’ve tried to add a package to Buildroot that uses Qt and Boost. The package uses qmake to generate a Makefile, this part seems to be working, however I get an error when I build saying:

```
Could not find qmake configuration file qws/linux-arm-g++.
Error processing project file: MsgDisplay.pro
```

The contents of my package is laid out like this:

```
DummyPgm
├── main.cpp
├── MsgDisplay.pri
├── MsgDisplay.pro
├── MsgDisplay.pro.user
├── MsgHandler.cpp
├── MsgHandler.h
├── MsgServer.cpp
├── MsgServer.h
├── Tcp
│   ├── TcpAddrPort.cpp
│   ├── TcpAddrPort.h
│   ├── TcpServer.cpp
│   ├── TcpServer.h
│   ├── TcpSocket.cpp
│   └── TcpSocket.h
└── Tools
    ├── Banner.cpp
    ├── Banner.h
    ├── IoExt.h
    ├── SeparateArgumentList.cpp
    ├── SeparateArgumentList.h
    └── SysTypes.h

2 directories, 20 files
```

I have added a package directory, `dummypgm`, which contains `Config.in` and `dummypgm.mk` files. The contents of the files are:

Config.in:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_DUMMYPGM
    bool "dummypgm"
    help
      Foo Software.

      http://www.foo.com
```

dummypgm.mk:

```
DUMMYPGM_VERSION = 0.1.0
DUMMYPGM_SOURCE = DummyPgm-$(DUMMYPGM_VERSION).tar.gz

define DUMMYPGM_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    (cd $(@D); $(QT_QMAKE)  MsgDisplay.pro)
endef

define DUMMYPGM_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D)
endef


$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Since the package is hosted locally, I’ve simply put the `DummyPgm-0.1.0.tar.gz` in the dl directory.

I’ve also added the following to `package/Config.in`:

```
source "package/dummypgm/Config.in"
```

I’m a little lost as to why this doesn’t work, if anyone could help me I would be very grateful. Also, is there any way to call `$(eval $(qmake-package))` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Qt4 or Qt5 ? Your `package/dummypgm/Config.in` should have a `depends on` on one of them, and your `dummypgm.mk` should have a `DUMMYPGM_DEPENDENCIES = qt` or `DUMMYPGM_DEPENDENCIES = qt5base`.

My intuition is that you are using Qt5. In this case, you shouldn't call `$(QT_QMAKE)`, but `$(QT5_QMAKE)`.

Have a look at http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/qextserialport/qextserialport.mk for an example. Note that this example supports both Qt4 and Qt5, probably in your case you only need one of the two.

Also, you should really subscribe to the Buildroot mailing list, you would get a lot more answers than here.

Comment: Thanks, I subscribed yesterday and sent a mail but unfortunately I didn't get a reply. I will try your suggestions today.